# Value is not updated in the IF statement

Tags: python, if-statement, scope

I know this is a silly question, but I would like to know why dictx is not being updated? The functions returns dictx value ignoring the if block
Thanks

```
def testing_func(num):
    if num == 5:
       dictx = {'var1':'val1',
                'var2': num}
    dictx = {'var':'val1',
             'var2':'not five'}
    return dictx
```

Comment: The second assignment replaces the first assignment, they aren't combined.

Comment: If you want to merge dictionaries, use `dictx.update(...)`

Comment: Do you mean to use an else statement on the second part?

Comment: Did you intend the second one to be in an `else` statement?

Answer (score 4):

If you write a function in the following format:

```
if statement:
    //first action
//second action
```

the second action will be run regardless of whether the **if** statement is true or not.

If you want to make the second action only run if the **if** statement is not true then you must place it in an **else** statement.

```
if statement:
    //first action
else:
    //second action
```

In your case, even if the dictionary is updated with **num**, it will always get overwritten with **'not five'** afterwards.

Answer (score 2):

It is because, once you go through the if statement and the condition is evaluated to true. And the dictx variable is changed. But on the next line it gets overwritten by `dictx = {'hello':'goodbye','hello2':'not five'}`. It is always the same value (no matter what the num is). To fix this you can use an else statement and put the `dictx = {'hello':'goodbye','hello2':'not five'}` line nested in it.

Final result:

```py
def testing_func(num):
    if num == 5:
       dictx = ({'var1':'val1',
                'var2': num})
    else:
       dictx = {'hello':'goodbye',
             'hello2':'not five'}
    return dictx
```

Answer (score 2):

you problem is because of you assign your value in dicx after If statement.
you can change your code like this:

```
def testing_func(num):
    if num == 5:
       dictx = ({'var1':'val1','var2': num})
    else:
       dictx = {'hello':'goodbye','hello2':'not five'}
    return dictx
```